# Cannot import numpy in python

Tags: python, python-3.x, numpy, modulenotfounderror

Some days ago I uninstalled anaconda from my PC. I just wanted to write some codes and I got this error message. I reinstalled Python several times, different versions, deleted every relevantfiles, however I still get this message. First it's a `ModuleNotFound` error, after I install it with `pip` I get this error.

```
>>> import numpy as np
 ** On entry to DGEBAL parameter number  3 had an illegal value
 ** On entry to DGEHRD  parameter number  2 had an illegal value
 ** On entry to DORGHR DORGQR parameter number  2 had an illegal value
 ** On entry to DHSEQR parameter number  4 had an illegal value
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
  File "C:\Users\username\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python39\lib\site-packages\numpy\__init__.py", line 305, in <module>
    _win_os_check()
  File "C:\Users\username\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python39\lib\site-packages\numpy\__init__.py", line 302, in _win_os_check
    raise RuntimeError(msg.format(__file__)) from None
RuntimeError: The current Numpy installation ('C:\\Users\\username\\AppData\\Local\\Programs\\Python\\Python39\\lib\\site-packages\\numpy\\__init__.py') fails to pass a sanity check due to a bug in the windows runtime. See this issue for more information: tinyurl.com/y3dm3h86
```

If I print out my path it says the following:

```
['', 'C:\\Users\\username\\AppData\\Local\\Programs\\Python\\Python39\\python39.zip', 'C:\\Users\\username\\AppData\\Local\\Programs\\Python\\Python39\\DLLs', 'C:\\Users\\username\\AppData\\Local\\Programs\\Python\\Python39\\lib', 'C:\\Users\\username\\AppData\\Local\\Programs\\Python\\Python39', 'C:\\Users\\username\\AppData\\Local\\Programs\\Python\\Python39\\lib\\site-packages']
```

But when I check my actual system variables it only contains:

```
%AppData%/Local/Programs/Python/Python39/Scripts/
%AppData%/Local/Programs/Python/Python39/
```

What should I

Comment: Please follow the [link](https://developercommunity.visualstudio.com/content/problem/1207405/fmod-after-an-update-to-windows-2004-is-causing-a.html) that is provided at the end of the error message.

Comment: @MichaelSzczesny thank you, maybe I'm not that good at googling... but I even tried installing Python 3.8.6 before and still got the same problem. But anyway, it works now.